# Can I say "it was a pleasure meeting you" after a phone call?

Tags: expressions, expression-choice

Is it possible to say "it was a pleasure meeting you" after the phone call? Or should we better say ""it was a pleasure to talk to you"?

Comment: Unless it was a video call, I would refrain from using "meeting you."

Comment: What's wrong with speaking??

Comment: @RogerSinasohn not a perfect fit because the older question also mentions a video conference, in which case using the phrase "it was a pleasure meeting you" is acceptable but YMMV

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say "meet." Instead, I would say what is entirely standard to say, "It was a pleasure speaking with you," though this somewhat formal statement is usually reserved for business phone calls.